# Improper integral when the integrand goes to infinity.

Tags: improper-integrals

Is it true that if 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$$ then $f $ can not be integrable at the neighborhood of $+\infty$, hence the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}{f(x)dx}$ does not exist?

Comment: yes, that is true.

Comment: Can you please tell me the main reason behind this?

Comment: @palio Check your definition of integrability. What's one of the main conditions required on $f$?

Comment: @GitGud the limit : $\lim_{X\to +\infty}\int_0^Xf(x)dx$ must be finite.

Comment: **Hint:** If $f(x)>M$ for $x>a$ then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx>(b-a)M$ when $b>a$.